# Javascript Scrolling Image edge detection

Tags: javascript

Currently I am experimenting with a little Image Zoom/Scroller script that I am trying to create, and yes I know there are plugins out there that do this but I am developing this for a lightweight version and for learning to. The main problem I have now is, that I am not sure how to constrain my image scrolling to only the width and height of my image. I would like to set up my script to stop the image from scrolling when the user gets to a ceartin width or height of the image to stop the image from being scrolled out of the div. Below is a fiddle to my script, any suggestions or tips to help me move in the right direction would be much appreciated [click here to go to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WpMyU/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built one of these a while ago.

The principle is you listen to three events: `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove`.

Firstly, it's best to use a `div` and then set the image as the `background-image` of the `div`. This allows you to use `background-position` to move the image around inside the `div`. We'll call this `div` `#container`.

On `mousedown`, you record the coordinates of the background position of the image. On page load, these will be `0 0` (unless you've told it to be something else; we'll assume you haven't). When the `mousedown` event is fired, this is essentially the start of the drag operation, so you'll probably want to set some sort of `draggingStarted` variable.

On `mousemove`, you want to check if `draggingStarted` is true. If it is, work out the relative distance the mouse cursor has moved and change the background image coordinates accordingly.

On `mouseup` you want to set your `draggingStarted` variable to false. This is so that if the `mousemove` event is fired, the image position stays fixed.

Now, the problem you're asking about is that the solution given so far allows the background position coordinates to overshoot the image, so we'll get a partially blank `#container`. The solution to *this* problem is to record the dimensions of the image, and then when you're working out how far to move the background image (in the `mousemove` function), check to see whether the new background image coordinates are outside the bounds of the image. If they are, don't allow it!

Comment: thank you that will give me a start now, so do you think that me using  a di to hold the image that is postion absolute and the drag is what causes the image top and left pos to change is not a good as a method as doing the image a bg image for the div?

Comment: Hmm. Well, you could certainly try that method, but I've had success with `background-image`. You'll need to set the `div`'s `position` to `relative`, then absolutely position the image inside it. You'll need to hide the image spilling out of the div, so use `overflow: hidden` on the div.

Comment: that is exactly what i ahve, you should check my example above, follow the link

Comment: OK. See [this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/WpMyU/16/). Can you see how I've restrained the image scrolling in the `mousemove` function?